# ImagesField in TabularInline in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an Order model, and each order have many Images.

Image Model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

how can i show images in TabularInline for each order in django admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new method called `thumbnail` and then use it to display each image.

Something like

```
def thumbnail(self):
  return u'<img src="%s" />' % (self.image.url)

thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
```

and then in your `admin.py` file

```
fields = ( 'thumbnail', )
```